# How to change change Excel PivotCache from external source to table if external source includes measures

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, power-query, powerpivot

I've inherited a worksheet that contains an external connection via PowerQuery, which is connected in turn to 20 or so PivotTables and four or five common slicers. Users have complained about speed using the slicers (about 10 seconds to load) so I'm trying to streamline the worksheet.

I'd like to change the PivotCaches that the PivotTables reference from being built using an external source to an internal one (the data loaded to a table) to avoid overhead/slowdown from making an unnecessary callout to the external source (the data will be static once it's loaded). I've loaded the data source to a table in my worksheet and am attempting to use the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727564/excel-2010-change-data-source-of-pivot-table-from-external-to-worksheet-within to change the PivotCache that the PivotTables that are already present are using from the external source to this table. The users won't need to refresh the data (and won't even have a connection to the table that the PowerQuery references) so my hypothesis is that if I load the data into the workbook from the outset I'll get some speed savings here (especially as the table is relatively small - no more than 10k rows or so at any one time).

I understand that I can change the PivotCache from an external/OLAP source to an internal one using the steps at the above link as long as the columns in the data sources are the same - my problem arises because the first data source has measures specified that don't get carried through when I load the data as a table. Is there a way to load the data in the external connection as well as the measures that are specified there to the internal table?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Cloud you provide more information here?

Comment: The way you describe this, the PivotTables are the output of a Power Query transformation. Loading the data to a table and then Pivotting from that won't be any more efficient, at face value.
What exactly is slowing this down? What do users do that it then takes too long? Are they hitting "refresh all" by any chance? Maybe you need to exclude the PQ external data load step from the Refresh All (so it only refreshes on open, or when explicitly called, for example).

Comment: @AdamV the users are selecting/deselecting slicer parameters - when they do this the PivotTables take ten seconds or so to refresh. The data is the result of a PowerQuery transformation but the users won't have a connection to the DB/tables that the query references so my hypothesis was that if the data was loaded locally initially and then the slicing happened in the workbook and not externally some performance improvements would be seen - but maybe this isn't true?